# Javascript: Codeacademy: The lost numbers

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am working on a Javascript exercise [[1]](http://www.codecademy.com/courses/functions-in-javascript-2-0/2#!/exercises/4). Below is what I have written. I think, I am right. But it is obviously flawed. I do not have any clue what went wrong. Do you see?

I tried debugging. How do I debug? Do you see any mistake?

```
var lost = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];

var isLost = function (n) {
  for (var i=0; i++; i <lost.length ) {
    if ( n === lost[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
};


var ret = isLost(12);
if ( ret === true) {
  console.log('12 is a lost number');
}

var ret = isLost(16);
if ( ret === true ) {
  console.log('16 is a lost number');
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You got the `for` header wrong. Should be:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < lost.length; i++ )
```

Comment: +1  Wew!! Shoot me, I am such a dumbo.. But that still got me this. Not sure what is still wrong. 
`12 is a lost number
16 is not lost number
Oops, try again.`

Comment: @GP You got the return statements reversed. Inside the `if` statement it should be `return true`, and at the end of the function should be `return false`...

Answer (score 2):

> I tried debugging. How do I debug?

Use FireBug, or the debugger in Chrome.  Debugging is probably the single most important skill to have in any platform, so spend some time learning this as one of the first things you do.

Comment: +1  Thanks! I was using alert and then console.log. I am still need to get used to Firebug. Will do. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
var lost = [4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42];
var count = lost.length;

var isLost = function (n) {
 for (var i = 0; i < lost.length; i++) {
    if (n === lost[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false ;
};

if ( isLost(12) ) {
  console.log('12 is a lost number');
}

if ( isLost(16) ) {
  console.log('16 is a lost number');
}
```